# button onclick id change not working in Html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to change ID of textarea using onclick button. So I created two buttons across my field. Each on click run a function.

Issue: It just replace my id first time and second time when i click on second button it throws error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null at ti_pos_fun (index.html:491)"

```
HTML code-
<div>
<label for="usr">ti:</label> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" onclick="ti_pos_fun()"></i> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked' onclick="ti_neg_fun()"></i>
</div>
```

I am trying to use two buttons- example

Now when you click check button- ti runs the onclick function "ti_pos_fun".

Function are as follows

```
function ti_neg_fun ()
{
var a = document.getElementById("jsel");
a.id = "ti_neg";
//$("#ti_neg").text('angry');
document.getElementById('ti_neg').innerHTML = 'angry';
}
function ti_pos_fun ()
{
var a = document.getElementById("jsel");
a.id = "ti_pos";
 document.getElementById('ti_pos').innerHTML = 'hahahahaha';
 //$("#ti_pos").text('hahahaha');

}
```

Textarea code where these ids are going & their text.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <H3> textarea</H3>
    <textarea id = "jsel"></textarea> 
    </div>
```

1. You click on button 1 - check button
2. It gets id and text in textarea
3. When you click on button 2- uncheck button
4. It fails

Answer (score 3):

Its not working on 2nd click because you are overwriting the id of that element

```
//a.id = "ti_neg";
```

so on 2nd click there is no element with id `jsel` and below statement will return null and it will not work.

```
document.getElementById("jsel");
```

```js
function ti_neg_fun ()
{
var a = document.getElementById("jsel");
//a.id = "ti_neg";
//$("#ti_neg").text('angry');
document.getElementById('jsel').innerHTML = 'angry';
}
function ti_pos_fun ()
{
var a = document.getElementById("jsel");
//a.id = "ti_pos";
 document.getElementById('jsel').innerHTML = 'hahahahaha';
 //$("#ti_pos").text('hahahaha');

}
```

```html
<div>
<label for="usr">ti:</label> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" onclick="ti_pos_fun()">1</i> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked' onclick="ti_neg_fun()">2</i>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10">
    <H3> textarea</H3>
    <textarea id = "jsel"></textarea> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello, this looks good but these are different element, IDs are linked to different values
But thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because the ID isn't jsel anymore you need something like this, if it can't find jsel check for the ID the other function set and visa versa. EDIT: added snip that works.

```js
function ti_pos_fun ()
    {
    var a = document.getElementById("jsel");
    if (a != null){
    a.id = "ti_pos";
     document.getElementById('ti_pos').innerHTML = 'hahahahaha';
     //$("#ti_pos").text('hahahaha');
    }else{
    var a = document.getElementById("ti_neg");
    a.id = "ti_pos";
     document.getElementById('ti_pos').innerHTML = 'hahahahaha';
     //$("#ti_pos").text('hahahaha');
    }
    }

    function ti_neg_fun ()
    {
    var a = document.getElementById("jsel");
    if(a != null){
    a.id = "ti_neg";
    //$("#ti_neg").text('angry');
    document.getElementById('ti_neg').innerHTML = 'angry';
    }else{
    var a = document.getElementById("ti_pos");
    a.id = "ti_neg";
    //$("#ti_neg").text('angry');
    document.getElementById('ti_neg').innerHTML = 'angry';
    }
    }
```

```html
<div>
<label for="usr">ti:</label> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" onclick="ti_pos_fun()">postitive</i> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked' onclick="ti_neg_fun()">negative</i>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10">
    <H3> textarea</H3>
    <textarea id = "jsel"></textarea> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I added - class="textarea" in the textarea element" ;
I am trying to use "<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.textarea1').click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
</script>"

to extract ID which is working.

But not able to understand how to put this extracted ID into document.getelementbyid(extractedid) , I am doing this because there are more than 20 elements

Comment: So I get a json file. From that json keys, i create these IDs for every key so there are exact 18 of these ids.
There ids get parsed.
$("#cst_pos").text(obj["0"]['drivers_with_sentences']['cst']['Selected']);
            $("#cst_neg").text(obj["0"]['drivers_with_sentences']['cst']['Unselected']);

cst_pos goes into textarea when "check" is selected , and then ....  list goes on for 18 elements